# addEventListener keyPress doesn't register key presses

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function when a key is pressed. I've found the `window.addEventListener(type, handler)` function to do this when `type = "keyPress"`; however, that doesn't seem to call the handler when keys are pressed.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
window.addEventListener("keyPress", myEventHandler);

function myEventHandler(event){
    console.log(event);
}
```

After focusing on the browser window, I expect key presses to be logged in the console; however, pressing keys doesn't produce any output.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("keypress", myEventHandler, false);` - small `p`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SZ9TG/1/

Comment: Did you really load jQuery just for the DOM ready method? Why not just ditch the library and use `window.onload`?

Comment: I didn't know of window.onload at the time, I just recently started using JavaScript. @RUJordan

Comment: Check it out, it's good to know

Comment: If you're a n00b, it's a good idea to learn vanilla JS before jQuery (if you really need it, tho I don't recommend it).

Comment: @RUJordan `window.onload` waits for iframes and stuff. Use `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback)`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You must use lowercase p in keyPress

Comment: Typically answers on questions like this will be downvoted because it's a typographical error, just a heads up

Answer (score 11):

The event name must be `keypress` - small `p`

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", myEventHandler, false);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SZ9TG/1/)

Apart form that since you are using jQuery use a jQuery solution like

```
//no need to use dom ready since the event is added to window
$(window).keypress(function (e) {
    //use e.which
    var keyCode = e.which;
    console.log(e, keyCode, e.which)
    if (keyCode == 88) {
        console.log("You pressed W!");
        //alert("You pressed W!");
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SZ9TG/)

[event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

> The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode.
>   It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input. For
>   more detail, read about [event.charCode on the MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.charCode#Notes).

Answer (score 1):

You could always use this

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;

    if(keyCode == 87 || keyCode == 119){
        console.log("You pressed W!");
        alert("You pressed W!");
    }
});
```

And yes W is 87, w is 119. So check both